# html: Image doesn't change size in css

Tags: html, css

I want to change my image size with my style.css but it doesn't apply.

Here is my style:

```
    .headerImage {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

And here is how I'm trying to insert my image:

```
<div class="headerImage">
            <img src="/images/header-image.png" alt="your image">
        </div>
```

I tried this and it worked, but I want to have other images in different sizes. So this is not an option:

```
img {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are resizing the parent element. There are multiple ways to fix this.

You could:

Move the class to the image

```css
.headerImage {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img class="headerImage" src="//picsum.photos/1920/1080" alt="your image">
</div>
```

select the image  in the css

```css
.headerImage img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="headerImage">
  <img src="//picsum.photos/1920/1080" alt="your image">
</div>
```

or change the size of  the image  to 100%.

```css
.headerImage {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.headerImageWrapper {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="headerImageWrapper">
      <img class="headerImage" src="//picsum.photos/1920/1080" alt="your image">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in HTML

```
<div>
    <img class="headerImage" src="/images/header-image.png" alt="your image">
  </div>
```

Comment: That worked! Is there any way I can still apply the class in the <div>?

Comment: yes, you can do <div class="name">
    <img class="headerImage" src="/images/header-image.png" alt="your image">
  </div>

Comment: Anyways, glad I could help :D

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
.headerImage img 
  {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  }
```